# Vertial Slider and Auto Height in Swiper

Tags: swiper.js

I hope you are doing well and spending your great weekend.

I'm using the Swiper slider on my project and be facing the issue in combination between `direction: 'vertical'` and `autoheight: true`
How can I use the auto height with vertical slider?
is there a way to use them together?

autoheight and vertical swiper

Comment: Does your slides have height attribute set to something?